# I Can't Get Cross Compiling From Ubuntu To Windows Working

Tags: compiler-errors, rust, rust-cargo

I Want To Cross Compile Some Rust Code from Ubuntu to Windows, and receive an error about onexitbegin.

Tried to follow various suggestions, but they don't have my specific error message: 
    crt2.o:crtexe.c:  (.rdata$.refptr.__onexitend[.refptr.__onexitend]+0x0): undefined reference to `__onexitend'
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

```
cargo build --release --target x86_64-pc-windows-gnu
```

Expected to get something built, but it blows up.
The output says this: 
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: /home/vince/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/lib/crt2.o:crtexe.c:(.rdata$.refptr.__onexitbegin[.refptr.__onexitbegin]+0x0): undefined reference to `__onexitbegin'
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: /home/vince/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/lib/crt2.o:crtexe.c:(.rdata$.refptr.__onexitend[.refptr.__onexitend]+0x0): undefined reference to`__onexitend'

Answer (score 8):

### If you receive messages about an undefined reference to

__onexitbegin` or something similar, you may have an older version of crt2.o, instead of the version that ming has available to it. I did! (running on stable rust 1.35).

Try this in your terminal and see if it helps:

```bash
cd ~/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/lib/

mv crt2.o crt2.o.bak

cp /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/crt2.o ./
```

Your executable should now be built for windows.

Comment: Had similar issues under macos. I just had to adjust paths a bit.